# Instantiate a CoffeeScript class from a class name in a string

Tags: coffeescript

How do I instantiate a class in CoffeeScript when I only have the name of the class in a string?

```
class Dog
  bark:->
    "Woof"

className = "Dog"
dog = new className  # <--- I would like to create an instance here using the string
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a bit of foresight you can do this pretty easily *and* protect yourself against using `eval`. Keep a list somewhere of the classes that you want to instantiate by name:

```
class Dog
  bark:->
    "Woof"

# Or window.named_classes if you need to access
# `named_classes` globally (or just in another
# CoffeeScript file).
named_classes = { Dog: Dog }
```

and then use your lookup table instead of `eval`:

```
name = 'Dog'
dog  = new named_classes[name]
```

When you say `class Dog`, you end up with a local variable called `Dog`:

```
var Dog;
Dog = (function() { /* ... */ })();
```

and there's no way to get at a local JavaScript variable unless you store it somewhere that you can access by name. Also note that `eval` won't work if you define `Dog` in one CoffeeScript file and want to access it another, [CoffeeScript wraps each file in self-executing anonymous function to limit variable scope](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope):

> all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })()`; This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.
>
> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use, attach them as properties on **window**, or on the **exports** object in CommonJS.

Comment: To add to that, rather than collecting them after the fact, you might find it more convenient to namespace them to start with.

Somewhere before everything else: `myClasses = {}`

Later on: `class myClasses.Dog`

Finally: `dog = new myClasses["Dog"]`

Comment: @Chris: Yes, that's a good point. You could use `class window.Dog` or `class window.named_classes.Dog` but `window.Dog` risks polluting `window` and `window.named_classes.Dog` makes local access to `Dog` a bit cumbersome. You could also do `named_classes.Dog = class Dog ...` but that is, IMO, a bit ugly.

Comment: @Chris: Looks like we're editing comments at the same time (and my internet connection is dodgy!). Anyway, there are various ways to get the desired effect, the important thing is to store a reference to the class in an object somewhere so that it has a program-accessible name.

Comment: aye, all manner of options here. The actual container can be aliased locally too, so you could have `exp = window.named_classes` at the top, followed by `class exports.Dog` which leads to the alright `new exports.Dog` locally, which still being able to `new window.named_classes["Dog"]` from anywhere. Having said that, if you're already declaring `window.named_classes = {}` anyway, then you can forever after just refer to it as plain `named_classes` elsewhere.

Comment: What happens if you don't have a list of the classes beforehand?

I.E. If you are writing some kind of framework plugin system, where others are going to write plugins and give them names, after the fact?

I guess that if you always got the plugin writers to add their classes to your named_classes object then that would be OK.

Comment: @Pete: Right, they'd have to register their "public" classes with a master list somewhere.

Comment: I think that this is probably the right way to go.  If you are doing a plugin system, you require that the plugin developer adds their class to a global object, which you can then access by ["name"] accessor.

Answer (score 3):

If using CommonJS modules then can one do something like this?

file: Dog.coffee

```
class Dog
  sound: ()->
    "woof"
```

file: Cat.coffee

```
class Cat
  sound: ()->
    "meow"
```

file: Main.coffee

```
className = 'Dog'
Animal = require(className)
animal = new Animal
animal.sound
# => "woof"

className = 'Cat'
Animal = require(className)
animal = new Animal
animal.sound
# => "meow"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bare in mind this isn't very good code, but I couldn't think of a better way.

Using `eval`:

```
class Dog
  bark:->
    "Woof"


className = "Dog"
dog = new (eval(classname))()
```

I'll keep thinking.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this but I was hoping there would be a more attractive method.

Comment: Down vote for a very unnecessary call to eval. Avoid eval!
mu has the right answer here.

Comment: @ChrisSubagio I did say that it wasn't a good idea, I just couldn't think of a better one.

Comment: up vote because he said it was bad code even before you down voted. balance restored.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

dog.coffee

```
class Dog
  bark:->
    "Woof"
```

app.coffee

```
@Dog = require './dog'
className = "Dog"
dog = new @[className]
```

Comment: This is equivalent to:

class @Dog
  bark: ->
    "woof"

className = 'Dog'
dog = new this[className]

alert dog.bark()